# Why can't a boy born on Poonam/Purnima marry a girl born on the day of Amavasya?

Tags: marriage, kundali, panchang

Why can't a Boy born on Poonam or Purnima marry girl born on the day of Amavasya? What are the problems in Hindu religion for such a case?

Comment: from where you got this info that Boy born on Poonam or Purnima can not marry girl born on the day of Amavasya?

Comment: One of my friends' relative told me. So I became curious to know the truth.